# How to delete ttf file using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, truetype

I m facing a problem while deleting my plugin...The ttf(true-type-fonts) file which i m using, not deletes when i uninstall the plugin.. i tried many things for deleting it but nothing works.. i got this error when i uninstall the plugin:

```
Plugin could not be deleted due to an error: Could not fully remove the plugin(s) captcha/install-captcha.php.
```

when i delete this file from folder i m getting error that "The action couldn't be completed because the file is open in httpd.exe"

please suggest something, how can i delete it...

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open your Task Manager.
- Click the "Processes" Tab and search for `httpd.exe` and click the <kbd>End Process</kbd> button and Try again.

Comment: Is there a way to delete file using php?

Comment: You should make use of the `unlink()`. Just use `unlink('yourfile.ttf');`

Comment: Why are you trying to delete via PHP ?

Comment: m using this file in my captcha plugin so i want that when i uninstall the plugin this file will delete...

Comment: `You cannot delete the file because you are currently using it`.